# Bootstrap menu links not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a bootstrap theme, and i kind of edited it to my needs.
Internal links (on the same page) are working, but external links are not clickable with the left mouse button. When i right click and open a link in a different tab it does work. I have no clue on what i did wrong, as i have not massively destroyed the code, just edited it to my needs([link](http://bit.ly/1ON038g)).

```
<li><a href="#body">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#info">information</a></li>
<li><a href="#server">Server</a></li>
<li><a href="#packages">packages</a></li>
<li><a href="//xxxxx">forum</a></li>
<li><a href="//xxxxx/">Donate</a></li>
```

the links with a # infront of them do work but externals do not.

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: External links work with complete urls like so: `<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: does not work either :(

Comment: there is no reason why that wouldn't work.  something else is going on.  try checking the console for errors

Comment: @c00ki3s I've tried http:// and // which should both work for external links,

Comment: @scottSelby I've checked my console, and i fixed the errors, but unfortunately it does not affect the issue i'm having. It does show the link when i hover over, but its not clickable with the left mouse button, however when i right click and open in different tab it does work.

Comment: You can have a look at http://bit.ly/1ON038g as you may see all links internal work, however the external links are not click able for some reason, they get highlighted tho, there just not left clickable

Comment: Hello @Cyph3r__ can you tell me which links not working as I can see all links work properly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `singlePageNav()` function you just need to add `external` class to external link.

**Updated HTML**

```
<li><a href="#body" class="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#info" class="">information</a></li>
<li><a href="#server" class="">Server</a></li>
<li><a href="#packages" class="">packages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://forum.lvcnr.org/forum.php" class="external">forum</a></li>
<li><a href="http://donate.lvcnr.org/" class="external">Donate</a></li>
```

Hope this will work.

For more info here is an [example](http://chriswojcik.net/demos/single-page-nav/) of same [single-page-nav](https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav) plugin.

Comment: How would i add that class, im new to this.

Comment: Use the html i have provided in the post above. or just add `class="external"` this to external link containig `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

you have a click handler somewhere that has code that is preventing the click from working.  I am guessing that this is the evil line , I really don't know fr sure I didn't go through all your js files:

```
jQuery('#nav').singlePageNav({
```

I don't know what `singlePageNav()` does , but I'd be willing to bet that is probably the root cause

I'm not going to search through your entire code to find it , but I do know for sure that is what is going on.  If you go into the console and type this:

```
$('#nav li a').off('click');
```

then the links go back to working like normal.

This goes back to my original comment that there is nothing at all wrong here , there is something else going on.  In this case you have some other code off somewhere else targeting these links preventing them from working.

Comment: Seems you are right, it went to behave like this after i removed some irrelevant stuff i did not need, ill try to find the code preventing from clicking. ---- Cant i add that partition of the code in main.js so it will be like life-time enabled